# Why doesn't ffmpeg respect my choice of video codec when capturing audio?

Tags: ffmpeg

Following [these instructions and examples](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Capture/Desktop) to record my screen, I used the following command:

```
ffmpeg -video_size 800x600 -framerate 60 -f x11grab -i :0.0 -c:v r210 test.mkv
```

I have explicitly chosen the `r210` codec as it is lossless (and uncompressed; I will pay the encoding penalty after I am finished recording), and `ffmpeg` is fine with this:

```
Output #0, matroska, to 'test.mkv':
Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf58.45.100
    Stream #0:0: Video: r210 (r210 / 0x30313272), gbrp10le, 800x600, q=2-31, 958464 kb/s, 60 fps, 1k tbn, 60 tbc
    Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavc58.91.100 r210
```

But this is not enough: I also want audio. Following the examples given, I come up with:

```
ffmpeg -video_size 800x600 -framerate 60 -f x11grab -i :0.0 -c:v r210 -f pulse -ac 2 -i default -c:a copy test.mkv
```

What happens?

```
Output #0, matroska, to 'test.mkv':
Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf58.45.100
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (libx264) (H264 / 0x34363248), yuv444p, 800x600, q=-1--1, 60 fps, 1k tbn, 60 tbc
    Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavc58.91.100 libx264
    Side data:
    cpb: bitrate max/min/avg: 0/0/0 buffer size: 0 vbv_delay: N/A
    Stream #0:1: Audio: pcm_s16le ([1][0][0][0] / 0x0001), 48000 Hz, stereo, s16, 1536 kb/s
```

`ffmpeg` has chosen to use h264 (libx264) instead, and I have no idea why. I have a feeling it has something to do with the intricacies around `ffmpeg`'s argument ordering, but remain stumped.

Comment: Have you tried placing `-c:v r210` between `-i default` and `-c:a copy`?

Comment: I did, and that did indeed work. Do you want to post that as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you have an addition input (`-i`), the `-c` before it will be considered as your choice of decoder for corresponding the input stream(s). I suppose ffmpeg silently ignore `-c:v r210` before `-f pulse -ac 2 -i default` as there are no video stream(s) in the input.

To specify the video encoder to use for the output, place the `-c` (`-c:v r210` in this case) after all the `-i`s.